# Google Chart access fill property of path

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to access fill property of a series in a stacked area (Google charts). I want the bottom series of the stacked chart to become transparent as shown in the JSFiddle code.

Can one please assist in this please? Your help is very much appreciated.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <!-- Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>

</div>

     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

           function drawChart() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
            ['2013', 1000, 400],
            ['2014', 1170, 460],
            ['2015', 660, 1120],
            ['2016', 1030, 540]
          ]);

          var options = {
              isStacked: true,
              title: 'Company Performance',
              hAxis: { title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: { color: '#333' } },
              vAxis: { minValue: 0 },
              series:
              {
                  0: { id: 'ss223', type: 'area', backgroundColor: { fill: 'black' } },
                  1: { type: 'area', backgroundColor: { fill: 'transparent' }}
              }
          };

          var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace...
`backgroundColor: { fill: 'transparent' }`

with...
`color: 'transparent'`

the series will be numbered, starting with zero on the bottom

see following working snippet...

note: if you want to make the area solid black, not just the border,
add this to your `options`...
`areaOpacity: 1`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Line 1', 'Line 2'],
      ['2013', 1000, 400, 200, 400],
      ['2014', 1170, 460, 200, 400],
      ['2015', 660, 1120, 200, 400],
      ['2016', 1030, 540, 200, 400]
    ]);

    var options = {
      isStacked: true,
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: { title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: { color: '#333' } },
      vAxis: { minValue: 0 },
      series:
      {
        0: { id: 'ss223', type: 'area', color: 'transparent' },
        1: { type: 'area', color: 'black' },
        2: { type: 'line', color: 'red' },
        3: { type: 'line', color: 'blue' }
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Wow that's great WhiteHat, that is perfect. Just a small question before I accept the answer. If I had to add a lineChart to the combo chart, where only the areas are stacked, i.e. the isStacked property should be set to true only to the area and not the line chart. How could that be so as to keep with this solution please? The reason I am asking this is because when I add isStacked:true in options, it also considers the linechart as stacked aswell, which I don't want.

Comment: according to the documentation, if `isStacked` is set to true, series elements of the _same type_ are stacked. and _only affects_ bar, column and area series only. -- i've added two line series to the answer above, they appear correctly and _not_ stacked...